# Convergence of integral to infinity

Tags: calculus

Let $p\geq1$. How can I study the convergence of the integral

$$ \int_1^{+\infty} \Bigg( \frac{\log x}{x} \Bigg)^p dx $$

without the substitution $x=\exp(t)$?

Comment: Is $p$ any real number $\geq 1$, or is $p = \{1, 2, \dots \}$?

Comment: $p \in \mathbb {R}$ and $p \geq 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p \geq 1$, let $f_p$ be the function defined by
$$
f_p\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{x}\right)^{p}
$$
Then the function $f_p$ is continuous and positive on $\left[1,+\infty\right[$. We search for $x^{\alpha}$ so that $x^{\alpha}f_p\left(x\right) \underset{x \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0$ with $\alpha>1$.
$$
x^{\alpha}f_p\left(x\right)=x^{\alpha-p}\ln^p\left(x\right)
$$

$\bullet$ First, suppose that $p>1$. Then it exists $\alpha \in \left]1,p\right[$.
Then
$$
x^{\alpha-p}\ln^p\left(x\right)\underset{x \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0
$$
meaning that
$$
f_p\left(x\right)\underset{(+\infty)}{=}o\left(\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}\right)
$$
With $\alpha>1$ you know that $\displaystyle x \mapsto \frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$ is integrable on $\left[1,+\infty\right[$ hence $f_p$ is integrable on $\left[1,+\infty\right[$.

$\bullet$ Suppose now that $p=1$. Then for some $N>e$
$$
\int_{1}^{N}f_1\left(x\right)\text{d}x=\int_{1}^{e}f_1\left(x\right)\text{d}x+\int_{e}^{N}f_1\left(x\right)\text{d}x
$$
For the second integral, we can use that for $x \in \left[e,+\infty\right[$
$$
\frac{1}{x} \leq f_1\left(x\right)
$$
And you know that $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is not integrable on $\left[1,+\infty\right[$. So $f_1 : x \mapsto \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ is not integrable on $\left[1,+\infty\right[$.

Answer (score 3):

For $p=1$, we have $\dfrac{\log x}{x}\geq\dfrac{1}{x}$ for all $x\geq 3$, then 
\begin{align*}
\int_{3}^{\infty}\dfrac{\log x}{x}dx\geq\int_{3}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}dx=\infty.
\end{align*}
For $1<p<\infty$, let $\eta\in(0,1)$ to be determined later. Then $\log x\leq x^{\eta}$ for large $x$, so
\begin{align*}
\int_{c_{\eta}}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{\log x}{x}\right)^{p}dx&\leq\int_{c_{\eta}}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^{(1-\eta)p}}dx<\infty,
\end{align*}
whenever $(1-\eta)p>1$, so $\eta$ can be taken in $(0,1-1/p)$.